# I want to this Script"music" and gameobject"mp" to stop playing when i change from my current scene"L1" to any other scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code runs perfectly for my first scene where the audio doesn't get reloaded each time the scene is reloaded, but I want different Audio's for different scenes.I tried creating new scripts for each scene but the after the next scene is loaded the old audio is still playing.
How do I destroy the GameObject.

I tried using the Scene indexes as a way to Destroy the object, but it didn't go the way I wanted to.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class music : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake() 
    {
        int numMusic = FindObjectsOfType<music>().Length;
        int currentindexscene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        int next = currentindexscene+1;
        Debug.Log("CURRENT "+currentindexscene);
        Debug.Log("NEXT "+next);

        if (numMusic >  1)    //no looping 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else if ( currentindexscene==1)   //not working 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); // doesnt stop the audio if the scene is refreshed 
        }
    }
}

// how do i destroy the object or script when i move to the next scene,
```

Comment: You can set music script to DontDestroyOnLoad and destroy any other copy of that. Also use [OnSceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) event to track the current loaded scene and according to that set your music.

Comment: The code in Awake cannot loop. Do you want to sync sound across scene

Answer (score 0):

You use `DontDestroyOnLoad` so this object will not be destroyed.

Have in mind that for this object `Awake` already ran once so it will never be re-checked!

Further there is also no guarantee that this instance is destroyed (e.g. hooking up to `SceneManager.sceneLoaded`) **before** the newly loaded instance already destroys itself due to the singleton check in its `Awake`.

---

This is not direly answering your question but rather the underlying issue:

=> I would rather stick to a single instance forever and instead provide a catalogue of audio clips for each scene to it.

For this

- first have some serializable scene reference like e.g. from [from here](https://github.com/JohannesMP/unity-scene-reference))
- Then combine this with a serializable Dictionary like e.g. [from here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/serializabledictionary-90477) or [here](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-SerializableDictionary)
- And then you could simply setup a `ScriptableObject` holding all your scenes music clips like e.g.

  ```
  [CreateAssetMenu]
  public class SceneMusicCatalogue : ScriptableObject
  {
      [Tooltip("Returned if a scene isn't explicitly listed below")]
      [SerializeField] AudioClip fallbackClip;
      [SerializeField] SerializableDictionary<SceneReference, AudioClip> sceneClips;

      private Dictionary<string, AudioClip> sceneClipsPaths;

      public AudioClipInfo GetClip(Scene scene)
      {
          if(sceneClipsPaths == null)
          {
              foreach(var kvp in sceneClips)
              {
                 sceneClipsPaths[kvp.Key] == kvp.value; 
              }
          }

          if(sceneClipsPaths.TryGetValue(scene.path, out var clip)
          {
              return clip;
          }

          return fallbackClip; 
      }
  }
  ```
- and finally you could use this in your one single manager instance like e.g.

  ```
  [RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
  public class Music : MonoBehaviour
  {
     private static Music instance;

      [SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;
      [SerializeField] private SceneMusicCatalogue sceneMusicCatalogue;

      void Awake() 
      {
          if(instance)
          {
              Destroy(this);
              return;
          }

          DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
          instance = this;

          if(!audioSource) audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
          SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
      }

      void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
      {
          var clipInfo = sceneMusicCatalogue.GetClip(scene);

          if(audioSource.clip != clipInfo.Clip)
          {
              audioSource.clip = clipInfo.Clip;
              audioSource.Play();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

One could of course refactor this a bit more to only have one dictionary e.g. (would just need to add some more operators and `IEquitable` implementation etc.